# Replacing a single numeric value in a string containing multiple copies of the same numeric value to be replaced

Tags: r, replace

I want to remove a specific numeric value, as well as text, in the first part of a string without changing the numeric values in the latter part of the string.
 The problem is the script I wrote if the numeric values to be replaced is equivalent to the numbers I do not want to be replaced everything changes:
Original text string: `DA1*01:01:01`

```
qlaST$DA1.1new <- gsub("[DA1*]", "", qlaST$DA1.1, perl = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
0:0:0
```

but I want to generate

```
01:01:01.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gsub("DA[0-9]\\*", "", 'DA1*01:01:01')
[1] "01:01:01"
```

or id the 'DA' literal is followed by an unknown number of digits you can add '*' after the [0-9] to include any number of digits you may have 
ie :

```
gsub("DA[0-9]*\\*", "", 'DA1234569*01:01:01')
[1] "01:01:01"
```

Comment: Thanks Mouad but it doesn't work because in my file I have many different numeric combinations containing '1', e.g. 05:05:01:01, 01:03:01:02, 02:01:01:01, 09:01:01, 09:01:02 etc. So I need a more general formula.

Comment: I suppose if you post a list of your inputs and outputs we would have a better idea.

Comment: Thank you it worked!. In the future I will give a more detailed description of my input file.

Comment: I am glad it worked, please consider upvoting the answer and clicking the check mark to indicate your satisfaction with it.